# how can i make my navbar and multiple carousel responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made a multiple carousel header and everything looks pretty good in my desktop but when the device size changes the images overlap each other and the navbar is not responsive either,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA1oN.jpg) i have tried everything but i am not able to fix it pls help
my problem:

[click here to see my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA1oN.jpg)

this is the code:

```
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none; }
.mySlides1 {display: none; }
.mySlides2 {display: none; }
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot2 {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.dot1 {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
   -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


.btn {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #c7a343;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.champu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 6em;
  left: 10em;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#9caaa9;
}

.img{
  width: 40em;
  height: 30em !important;
  object-fit: cover !important;

}

</style>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-image: url(background-.jpg);">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="slideshow-container"  style=" padding-left:0 !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/living-room/pic2.png" style="margin-top:9em; height: 30em !important; padding-left:1em !important; width: 37em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Living Room</h3>
  <a href="collections-livingroom.html">
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 50%;">View Collection</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/living-room/pic1.png" style="margin-top:9em; height: 30em !important; padding-left:1em !important; width: 37em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Living Room</h3>
  <a href="collections-livingroom.html">
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 50%;">View Collection</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/living-room/pic3.png" style="margin-top:9em; height: 30em !important; padding-left:1em !important; width: 37em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Living Room</h3>
  <a href="collections-livingroom.html">
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 50%;">View Collection</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/living-room/pic4.png" style="margin-top:9em; height: 30em !important; padding-left:1em !important; width: 37em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Living Room</h3>
  <a href="collections-livingroom.html">
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 50%;">View Collection</button>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
</div><!-- col-md-4-->

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="slideshow-container" style="width: 43em !important; padding-right:4em !important; padding-left:0.2em; margin-left:0 !important;">

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/bedroom/pic2.jpg" style="margin-top:9em; width: 45em !important; height: 30em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Bedroom</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/bedroom/pic1.jpg" style="margin-top:9em; width: 45em !important; height: 30em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Bedroom</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/bedroom/pic3.jpg" style="margin-top:9em; width: 45em !important; height: 30em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Bedroom</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

<div class="mySlides1 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/bedroom/pic4.jpg" style="margin-top:9em; width: 45em !important; height: 30em !important;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Bedroom</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>


</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot1"></span> 
  <span class="dot1"></span> 
  <span class="dot1"></span> 
  <span class="dot1"></span> 
</div>
</div><!-- col-md-4-->

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="slideshow-container" style="padding-right:13em !important; width:50em; padding-left:1em;">

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/outdoor/pic2.jpg" style="margin-top:9em;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Outdoor</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/outdoor/pic1.jpg" style="margin-top:9em;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Outdoor</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/outdoor/pic3.jpg" style="margin-top:9em;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Outdoor</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

<div class="mySlides2 fade">
  <img src="slider-pics/outdoor/pic4.jpg" style="margin-top:9em;" class="img">
  <h3 class="champu" style="top: 40%; left: 25%;">Outdoor</h3>
  <button class="btn" style="top: 85%; left: 40%;">View Collection</button>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot2"></span> 
  <span class="dot2"></span> 
  <span class="dot2"></span> 
  <span class="dot2"></span> 
</div>
</div><!-- col-md-4-->
</div> <!-- col-md-12-->
</div><!-- row -->





<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); 
}

var slideIndex1 = 0;
showSlides1();

function showSlides1() {

  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot1");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex1++;


  if (slideIndex1 > slides.length) {slideIndex1 = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex1-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex1-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides1, 2000); 
}


var slideIndex2 = 0;
showSlides2();

function showSlides2() {

  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot2");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex2++;


  if (slideIndex2 > slides.length) {slideIndex2 = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex2-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex2-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides2, 4000); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest making use of a responsive CSS framework like Bootstrap that would handle most of this for you. Bootstrap has an in built option for a responsive header, it has responsive columns that would take care of your carousel on the screens. If you want to reinvent the wheel by writing all this responsive css yourself, you will have to write quite a lot of code for responsiveness which is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query in CSS styling so you can design it as per the device size so that your images don't overlap
You can go through this for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Please provide example in your answers to help the Asker better than just directing to the reference material